# is there a way to use > and < with Strings?

Tags: java

i want to ask the user to input a number between 0 and 180. but the variable has to be a String.

```
// Saisie du nombre de jours de location
            System.out.println("Entrez le nombre de jours de location (supérieur à 0 et inférieur ou égal à 180) : ");
            nbJoursLouer = Clavier.lireString();
            while ( nbJoursLouer < "0" || nbJoursLouer > "180") {
                System.out.println("Entrée invalide !");
                System.out.println("Entrez le nombre de jours de location (supérieur à 0 et inférieur ou égal à 180) : ");
                nbJoursLouer = Clavier.lireString();
            }
```

when i run and input a letter instead of a number, i get this message:

```
Entrez le nombre de jours de location (supérieur à 0 et inférieur ou égal à 180) : 
d
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "d"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at Tp1.main(Tp1.java:100)
```

Comment: Cast or parse it as an int

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: The stack trace says that the error is on line 100 of `Tp1.java`, where you're calling `parseInt`, on a value that's not a number.  Presumably, that's not the code that you've shown here.

Comment: @JonR85 you can't cast a `String` to an `int`.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't compile. How are you getting a runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `<` and `>` for String in Java, it's a compile error. The closest equivalent is `String.compareTo(String)`, which won't work how you intend it to: "100" would be less than "18" because strings are ordered lexicographically and Java won't try to be "smart" like JavaScript. Hence, you must convert your string to integers explicitly. Have a look at [this related question for how to use `Integer.parseInt()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The error message you shared shows that `Integer.parseInt()` is used somewhere. It tries to convert the string to a number by reading it character by character. But when it encounters a character that is invalid for integers (letters, special characters...), it will fail with the exceptions you are seeing. By using a `try-catch` clause, you can react to that and handle it by returning an error message similar to the one in your code.

```
int lireNombre() {
  while (true) {
    System.out.println("Entrez le nombre de jours de location (supérieur à 0 et inférieur ou égal à 180) : ");
    try {
      int value = Integer.parseInt(Clavier.lireString());
      if (value > 0 || value <= 180) {
        return value;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Ce n'est pas supérieur à 0 et inférieur ou égal à 180!");
      }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
      System.out.println("Ce n'est pas un nombre!");
    }
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("We should never have gotten here");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u must convert String to an Integer

```
Integer n = Integer.valueOf(nbJoursLouer);
while ( n < 0 || n > 180)
```

the nbJoursLouer variable is not a number 
it's just the letter "d" 
Your code is wrong.

Comment: that's true, but even though his code is a complete dumpster fire it looks like his issue is handling what happens when a NumberFormatException is thrown.